# Facilitar contagem entre colunas - Python

Tags: python, condição

Estou iniciando no python e tenho dificuldades para automatizar alguns cálculos. Possuo um DataFrame com 8 colunas [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H] e 150 linhas.

Preciso contabilizar quantas vezes 2 colunas são iguais entre si, por exemplo: A==B, A==C, A==D... B==C, B==D... Depois preciso dividir a quantidade de igualdades pelo número total de linhas (150) e armazenar esse resultado em outra tabela. Até o momento consegui isso:

```
condicao = (df['A']==df['B'])
sum(condicao)

x = sum(condicao)/150
print(x)
```

Com esse código já consigo o resultado que preciso, porém, seria necessário criar 28 condições. Alguma ideia de como resumir isso?

Abraços.

Comment: As colunas precisam ser iguais em todas as entradas ou você quer contabilizar o número de entradas em comum entre duas colunas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(no caso em que você queira contabilizar o número de entradas iguais para cada possível par de colunas)*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


Colunas = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']


Duplas = [Colunas[i]+Colunas[j] for i in range(8) for j in range(i+1, 8)]
Duplas = np.array(Duplas)


@np.vectorize
def ContaDuplas(Dupla):

    return np.sum(df[Dupla[0]] == df[Dupla[1]])



NovaTabela = pd.DataFrame({'Contagem': ContaDuplas(Duplas)/150}, index=Duplas)
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu estava precisando, com essa nova tabela eu consigo montar uma matriz. Muito obrigado.